# Rails query a has_many :through conditionally with multiple ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a filtering system for a website that has locations and features through a LocationFeature model. Basically what it should do is give me all the locations based on a combination of feature ids.

So for example if I call the method:

```
Location.find_by_features(1,3,4)
```

It should only return the locations that have **all** of the selected features. So if a location has the feature_ids [1, 3, 5] it *should not* get returned, but if it had [1, 3, 4, 5] it *should*. However, currently it is giving me Locations that have **either** of them. So in this example it returns both, because some of the feature_ids are present in each of them.

Here are my models:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_features, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :features, through: :location_features

  def self.find_by_features(*ids)
    includes(:features).where(features: {id: ids})
  end
end

class LocationFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :feature
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_features, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :locations, through: :location_features
end
```

Obviously this code isn't working the way I want it to and I just can't get my head around it.  I've also tried things such as:

```
Location.includes(:features).where('features.id = 5 AND features.id = 9').references(:features)
```

but it just returns nothing. Using OR instead of AND give me either again.  I also tried:

```
Location.includes(:features).where(features: {id: 9}, features: {id: 1})
```

but this just gives me all the locations with the feature_id of 1.

What would be the best way to query for a location matching all the requested features?

Comment: Which dbms is it?  Mysql, postgres, sqlite etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as a set of subqueries.  You can actually also do it as a scope if you wish.

```
scope :has_all_features, ->(*feature_ids) {
  where( ( ["locations.id in (select location_id from location_features where feature_id=?)"] * feature_ids.count).join(' and '), *feature_ids)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do an include it makes a "pseudo-table" in memory which has all the combinations of table A and table B, in this case joined on the foreign_key.  (In this case there's already a join table included (feature_locations), to complicate things.)

There won't be any rows in this table which satisfy the condition `features.id = 9 AND features.id = 1`.  Each row will only have a single `features.id` value.

What i would do for this is forget about the features table:  you only need to look in the join table, `location_features`, to test for the presence of specific `feature_id` values.  We need a query which will compare feature_id and location_id from this table.

One way is to get the features, then get a collection of arrays if associated location_ids (which just calls the join table), then see which location ids are in *all* of the arrays:  (i've renamed your method to be more descriptive)

```
#in Location
def self.having_all_feature_ids(*ids)
  location_ids = Feature.find_all_by_id(ids).map(&:location_ids).inject{|a,b| a & b}
  self.find(location_ids)
end
```

Note1: the asterisk in `*ids` in the params means that it will convert a list of arguments (including a single argument, which is like a "list of one") into a single array.

Note2: `inject` is a handy device.  it says "do this code between the first and second elements in the array, then between the result of this and the third element, then the result of **this** and the fourth element, etc, till you get to the end.  In this case the code i'm doing between the two elements in each pair (a and b) is "&" which, when dealing with arrays, is the "set intersection operator" - this will return only elements which are in both pairs.  By the time you've gone through the list of arrays doing this, only elements which are in ALL arrays will have survived.  These are the ids of locations which are associated with ALL of the given features.

EDIT: i'm sure there's a way to do this with a single sql query - possibly using `group_concat` - which someone else will probably post shortly :)

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! However if I try this it gives me a no method error for Feature.find_all_by_id - any idea why?

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is a rails version thing: `find_all_by_` has been deprecated in Rails 4.  Replace `Feature.find_all_by_id(ids)` with `Feature.where(["id in (?)", ids])`