# Active Record multiple condition on a single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following model associations:

```rb
class PartOfSpeech < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :part_of_speech_words
  has_many :words, through: :part_of_speech_words
end

class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :part_of_speech_words
  has_many :part_of_speeches, through: :part_of_speech_words
end

class PartOfSpeechWord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part_of_speech
  belongs_to :word
end
```

I have given with a set of `part_of_speech_ids` say [1,2,3]. With these associations, I have to find all the words which has all these part_of_speeches. A word with `part_of_speech_ids` [1,2,3,4] must show up, but not a word with only [1,2].

Querying with **IN** will not give the right result as it performs an **OR** operation. I want something that performs **AND** on the array elements.

Please help.

Comment: Please look into it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143595/rails-query-a-has-many-through-conditionally-with-multiple-ids

Answer (score 0):

Given you have unique indexes for `word_id` and `part_of_speech_id` in your join table, you can just count mathching records:

```
word_ids = PartOfSpeechWord.
  select('min(word_id) AS word_id').
  where(part_of_speech_id: part_of_speech_ids).
  group_by(:part_of_speech_id).
  having('COUNT(part_of_speech_id) >= ?', part_of_speech_ids.size).
  map { |x| x['word_id'] }

word = Word.where(id: word_ids)
```

Comment: When my part_of_speech_ids is [1,2,3], is there any way to order results which matches [1,2,3], then [1,2] and last [1]. I know this was not my earlier requirement. But need to add this too in the logic

Comment: You can, for example, run a series of queries. But it sounds easier to introduce some kind of cache — you can add `part_of_speech_ids` array attribute to `Word` model, and update it whenever needed to cache IDs of related records (`after_touch` callback will be helpful here). Then just query that attribute.